# A typical bracket balanced problem in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, brackets

I'm trying to create a function which returns a boolean value to see if the string is balanced. But the result is just not what I expect. Can someone point out what I did wrong?

For example:

```
false = is_balanced")("
false = is_balanced "(a)b)"
true = is_balanced "fo"
true = is_balanced "a(b(c)d)e"
```

```
let rec list_car ch = match ch with
  | "" -> []
  | ch -> (String.get ch 0 ) :: (list_car (String.sub ch 1 ( (String.length ch)-1) ) )  ;;

let is_balanced klm =
  let brk = list_car klm in
  let rec left = function
    | x::xs, 0 -> 
      if x = ')' then false 
      else left (xs, 0)
    | x::xs, level -> 
      if x = '(' then left (xs, succ level) 
      else if x = ')' then left (xs, pred level) 
      else left (xs, level)
    | [], level -> if level = 0 then true else false
  in 
  left (brk, 0) ;;
```

But I got the following results:

```
is_balanced "(((";;
- : bool = true
 is_balanced "()";;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: What is an example that doesn't work?

Comment: i 've added the wrong results

Comment: Style note: you don't need to use the conditionals. You can directly pattern match on values like `')'` and `'('`.  Like: `| '('::xs, 0 -> false | _::xs, 0 -> left (xs, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Exploding a string into a list of char by using `String.sub` is inefficient and unnecessary. Your code can be rewritten as

```
let is_balanced s =
  let rec count pos level =
    if (* termination condition *) ... then level = 0 
    else match s.[pos] with
     | '(' -> ...
     | ')' -> ...
     | _  -> ...
   in
   count 0 0
```

With this variant, your mistake should disappear by itself.

Indeed one possible root issue with your previous code is that you are matching on both the list of chars and the level and end up mixing the logic of the termination condition with the logic of the level counting.

In particular, should the level at position `n` influence the effect of characters on the level at the position `n+1`?

Comment: Thanks for helping me,but I'm still confused about your code,like how can i make argument pos, level move forward,and where can i end up with bool value, true or false,Could you pls finish your code? It will be a huge help for me.

Answer (score 3):

Presented as an alternative, this is a good opportunity to gain experience with folds. They work well in any situation where you are iterating over something one element at a time and need to evaluate that element in conjunction with an initial state to generate a new value.

The state we'll keep track of is the nesting level. It'll start out as `0`. Each iteration, if it's *less than* `0`, the nesting is obviously unbalanced. No further elements from the string will balance the parens, so we'll simply propagate this value to the end of the fold, resulting in a `false` return.

Otherwise we'll increment or decrement the levels as we encounter open and close parens. Or take no action for non-paren characters.

```
let balanced str =
  let f level ch =
    if level < 0 then 
      level
    else 
      match ch with
      | '(' -> level + 1
      | ')' -> level - 1
      | _   -> level
  in
  String.fold_left f 0 str = 0
```

```
# balanced ")(";;
- : bool = false
# balanced "(a)b)";;
- : bool = false
# balanced "fo";;
- : bool = true
# balanced "a(b(c)d)e";;
- : bool = true
```

Consider how this operates on `"(a)b)"`:

```
balanced "(a)b)"
String.fold_left f 0 "(a)b)"
String.fold_left f 1 "a)b)"
String.fold_left f 1 ")b)"
String.fold_left f 0 "b)"
String.fold_left f 0 ")"
String.fold_left f -1 ""
-1
-1 = 0
false
```

If we look at `"a(b(c)d)e"`:

```
balanced "a(b(c)d)e"
String.fold_left f 0 "a(b(c)d)e"
String.fold_left f 0 "(b(c)d)e"
String.fold_left f 1 "b(c)d)e"
String.fold_left f 1 "(c)d)e"
String.fold_left f 2 "c)d)e"
String.fold_left f 2 ")d)e"
String.fold_left f 1 "d)e"
String.fold_left f 1 ")e"
String.fold_left f 0 "e"
String.fold_left f 0 ""
0
0 = 0
true
```

The propagation of the negative level value can be seen if we test `"())hello()"`:

```
balanced "())hello()"
String.fold_left f 0 "())hello()"
String.fold_left f 1 "))hello()"
String.fold_left f 0 ")hello()"
String.fold_left f -1 "hello()"
String.fold_left f -1 "ello()"
String.fold_left f -1 "llo()"
String.fold_left f -1 "lo()"
String.fold_left f -1 "o()"
String.fold_left f -1 "()"
String.fold_left f -1 ")"
String.fold_left f -1 ""
-1
-1 = 0
false
```

One note about this approach: it does not *short circuit*. A string that starts with `)` will clearly result in `false` but the entire string will need to be iterated over.

One way around this would be to have our locally scoped `f` function raise an exception on `level` being negative, and then to handle this exception by returning `false`.

```
exception Unbalanced_parens

let balanced str =
  let f level ch =
    if level < 0 then 
      raise Unbalanced_parens
    else 
      match ch with
      | '(' -> level + 1
      | ')' -> level - 1
      | _   -> level
  in
  match String.fold_left f 0 str with
  | 0 -> true
  | _ | exception Unbalanced_parens -> false
```

Now, if we test `"())hello()"`:

```
balanced "())hello()"
String.fold_left f 0 "())hello()"
String.fold_left f 1 "))hello()"
String.fold_left f 0 ")hello()"
String.fold_left f -1 "hello()"
raise Unbalanced_parens
false
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
  |x::xs,0-> if x =')'then false else left(xs,0)
```

Here, if `x` is not `)`, the character is simply ignored. Hence, if it is instead `(`, `level` will not be incremented.

The quick fix is to instead match the character directly:

```
  | ')'::xs, 0 -> false
```

But I fully agree with @octachron's advice, and that the problem would have been avoided by not mixing list iteration and level counting.

Also, note that you can use `when` to attach a condition to a branch. For example, if you match on just the list, you could instead do:

```
  | ')'::xs when level = 0 -> false
```

And you could also do

```
  | ')'::xs when level < 0 -> false
```

which is unnecessary in this case, but serves to demonstrate a case that cannot be covered by pattern matching on `level` directly.

Answer (score 1):

When learning to program, it's important not only to learn programming techniques (such as algorithms) and programming languages, but also tools.

You're confronted with a problem: you've written some code that takes some input and returns the wrong input, but you don't understand why. There are two main approaches to this kind of problem:

- Break down the code into smaller pieces, and test them separately, until you find one (or more) that doesn't return the outputs you wanted.
- Use debugging tools to look at what's happening inside the program.

Here you can test `list_car` independently and see that it's not the source of the problem. There's not much you can do to break down `is_balanced`, but you can take out `left` and make it a top-level function.

```
let rec left = function
    | x::xs, 0 -> 
      if x = ')' then false 
      else left (xs, 0)
    | x::xs, level -> 
      if x = '(' then left (xs, succ level) 
      else if x = ')' then left (xs, pred level) 
      else left (xs, level)
    | [], level -> if level = 0 then true else false
;;
let is_balanced klm =
  let brk = list_car klm in
  left (brk, 0) ;;
```

That's not going to help directly, because the problem is inside `left` and it's all one thing that can't really be broken down into smaller pieces. However, making `left` a toplevel function allows you to use a simple debugging tool: [tracing](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/debug.html#Tracing-functions-calls-in-the-toplevel) in the toplevel. (A function doesn't have to be at the top level to debug it, but it does to use the toplevel's simple tracing function.)

```
# #trace left;;
left is now traced.
# is_balanced "()";;
left <-- (['('; ')'], 0)
left <-- ([')'], 0)
left --> false
left --> false
```

Now you can see where the code is going wrong: the second call to `left` is made with the level 0, but it should be 1 since the previous call opened a parenthesis. So the problem is that `left (['('; ')'], 0)` is passing the wrong level value when it makes its recursive call.

```
    | x::xs, 0 -> 
      if x = ')' then false 
      else left (xs, 0)
                     ^
```

Now that you've located the problem, the correction should be obvious: in the recursive call, you need to remember the number of opening parentheses somehow — that's what `level` is for. So `level` here should be 1, not 0.

```
let rec left = function
    | x::xs, 0 -> 
      if x = ')' then false 
      else left (xs, 1)
    | x::xs, level -> 
      if x = '(' then left (xs, succ level) 
      else if x = ')' then left (xs, pred level) 
      else left (xs, level)
    | [], level -> if level = 0 then true else false
;;
let is_balanced klm =
  let brk = list_car klm in
  left (brk, 0) ;;
```

(Remember that in the toplevel, after redefining `left`, you need to redefine `is_balanced` as well, even if its textual definition hasn't changed: the old definition refers to the old definition of `left`.)

I think `is_balanced` is now correct for inputs that consists solely of parentheses. It doesn't properly ignore other characters, but I'll let you debug that on your own. It may help to write the code in a simpler way, taking advantage of the fact that you can match on the first element of the list, on the level, or both. For example, the incorrect case above was actually unnecessary: you could have made the first case

```
    | ')'::xs, 0 -> false
```

and the second case already handles lists starting with `(` correctly: when the first character is `(`, the logic is the same regardless of the value of the level.

Comment: That helps a lot! Now i know where is the problem and more valueable is how to address them.I habe uploaded the fixed code which can take all input not only parentheses.I simply use pattern matching _::xs ->...to make it forward(keep the same level if it's not parentheses).Now i'more interested but also confused with the approach from @octachron

Answer (score 0):

Now I fixed mt code,and it works!Thanks a lot for the tipps

```
let rec list_car ch = 
  match ch with
  | "" -> []
  | ch -> String.get ch 0 :: list_car (String.sub ch 1 (String.length ch - 1))

let is_balanced klm =
  let brk = list_car klm in
  let rec left = function
    | ')'::xs, level ->
      if level > 0 then left (xs, pred level) else false
    | '('::xs, level -> left (xs, succ level)
    | _::xs, level -> left (xs, level)
    | [], level -> if level = 0 then true else false
  in 
  left (brk, 0)
```

Comment: Sequences provide a cleaner way to convert your string to a list.  `let list_char lst = lst |> String.to_seq |> List.of_seq`

Comment: Also please note that `if level = 0 then true else false` is just an overly verbose way to write `level = 0` and `if level > 0 then left (xs, pred level) else false` can be reduced to `level > 0 && left (xs, pred level)`